# AJAX won't send POST data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently working on a project which requires some AJAX, but for some reason my current code wont send the POST data.
here is my AJAX:

```
<script>
$('#greenon').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'command.php', 
            data : { "green" : "on" },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert("it worked!");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("didn't work!");
            }
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

And it's not even sending the 'didnt work' alert. I am using this in command.php (it would write the file if command.php got accessed,

```
<?php
$content = "bleh";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/file.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Why is it not sending POST data? thanks!

oh and here is my button HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" role="button" id="greenon">Turn On</a>
```

Comment: Check the javascript console and network tab of your browser's dev tools for errors.

Comment: You do have jquery included, right? :p

Comment: To back up @Oleg's answer, at what location is this script included in your page, particularly in relation to your link / button element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your JS code is **before** your's button HTML code, so the binding doesn't work. Put your JS **after** `<a>...</a>`, or frame it with `$(document).ready()` callback:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#greenon').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'command.php', 
            data : { "green" : "on" },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert("it worked!");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("didn't work!");
            }
    });

    return false;
});
});
</script>
```